# spotfire- how to find create a column to calculate the time of next stage

Tags: spotfire

I want to create a calculated column to show the time action end grouped by [Case ID], [Stage], and [Action]. The order of the stage is not necessary alphabetic and it could be duplicated. Say after [stage] 'C', we could have  another [stage] 'c' in the future

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: so what would determine the next time? Is the data sorted before import thus applying a custom sort is unnecessary? Are these data types truly characters?

Comment: thanks for replying! 1) next time will just be the time of the next stage. For example the next time for time a is time b beacuse Stage B comes after stage A. 2) It would be great if you can provide the method to sort the data by time. 3)data types are 'Date and Time', characters are just symbol to simplify.

Comment: Thanks @BenWang.  Can your provide a more realistic / actual data sample? The datatypes are very important in this case so the methods used for this test data wouldn't work on your real data. Cheers.

Comment: sure, i have edited my question. hope it makes more sense

Comment: Are there any date columns, or just time? This can be done both ways but more accurately with date columns in play

Comment: its just time. i am just creating dummy data, in my real project its date and time in the action time column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the updated test data. The data types are **extremely** important when asking. Also, the test data should mirror the actual data as close as possible, otherwise solutions often will not scale. For example, in the test data the values are only time. Sorting on time doesn't take into account the day, thus it's all treated equally.  Since these values are actually DateTime, I have added that to the test data. These expressions will give you the expected results as identified in your question.

1. `Rank([Time_Action_Begin],"asc",[Case ID]) as [Rank]`
2. `Min([Time_Action_Begin]) OVER (Intersect([Case ID],Next([Rank])))`

**RESULTS**

```
+---------+-------+----------+------------------------+------------------------+------+
| Case ID | Stage |  Action  |   Time_Action_Begin    |    Time_Action_End     | Rank |
+---------+-------+----------+------------------------+------------------------+------+
|       1 | A     | approve  | 01/01/2016 11:30:00 PM | 01/02/2016 12:30:00 AM |    1 |
|       1 | A     | approve  | 01/01/2016 11:30:00 PM | 01/02/2016 12:30:00 AM |    1 |
|       1 | B     | approve  | 01/02/2016 12:30:00 AM | 01/02/2016 1:30:00 AM  |    3 |
|       1 | B     | approve  | 01/02/2016 12:30:00 AM | 01/02/2016 1:30:00 AM  |    3 |
|       1 | C     | approve  | 01/02/2016 1:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 2:30:00 AM  |    5 |
|       1 | C     | approve  | 01/02/2016 1:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 2:30:00 AM  |    5 |
|       1 | D     | approve  | 01/02/2016 2:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 3:30:00 AM  |    7 |
|       1 | D     | approve  | 01/02/2016 2:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 3:30:00 AM  |    7 |
|       1 | E     | approve  | 01/02/2016 3:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 4:30:00 AM  |    9 |
|       1 | E     | approve  | 01/02/2016 3:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 4:30:00 AM  |    9 |
|       1 | F     | complete | 01/02/2016 4:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 5:30:00 AM  |   11 |
|       1 | F     | complete | 01/02/2016 4:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 5:30:00 AM  |   11 |
|       1 | C     | approve  | 01/02/2016 5:30:00 AM  |                        |   13 |
|       1 | C     | approve  | 01/02/2016 5:30:00 AM  |                        |   13 |
|       2 | A     | approve  | 01/01/2016 10:30:00 PM | 01/02/2016 12:30:00 AM |    1 |
|       2 | A     | approve  | 01/01/2016 10:30:00 PM | 01/02/2016 12:30:00 AM |    1 |
|       2 | B     | approve  | 01/02/2016 12:30:00 AM | 01/02/2016 2:30:00 AM  |    3 |
|       2 | B     | approve  | 01/02/2016 12:30:00 AM | 01/02/2016 2:30:00 AM  |    3 |
|       2 | C     | approve  | 01/02/2016 2:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 3:30:00 AM  |    5 |
|       2 | C     | approve  | 01/02/2016 2:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 3:30:00 AM  |    5 |
|       2 | D     | approve  | 01/02/2016 3:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 4:30:00 AM  |    7 |
|       2 | D     | approve  | 01/02/2016 3:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 4:30:00 AM  |    7 |
|       2 | E     | approve  | 01/02/2016 4:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 5:30:00 AM  |    9 |
|       2 | E     | approve  | 01/02/2016 4:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 5:30:00 AM  |    9 |
|       2 | F     | complete | 01/02/2016 5:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 6:30:00 AM  |   11 |
|       2 | F     | complete | 01/02/2016 5:30:00 AM  | 01/02/2016 6:30:00 AM  |   11 |
|       2 | C     | approve  | 01/02/2016 6:30:00 AM  |                        |   13 |
|       2 | C     | approve  | 01/02/2016 6:30:00 AM  |                        |   13 |
+---------+-------+----------+------------------------+------------------------+------+
```

Comment: is there anyway to take [case id] into account? i want the expression to be specified per each case id. i tried Min([Time_Action_Begin]) OVER intersect(NextPeriod([Time_Action_Begin]),[case id]). however, it is not giving me what i want.

Comment: @BenWang this is why it's important to provide ample test data and expected results. See updated answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i will keep that in mind in my future posting. can you please explain a bit about the next() method you use?

Comment: Sure thing @BenWang, NEXT() compared the current node (or row|column value) with the next node on the same level. Since We are using this on Rank, an integer column, it looks for what is sequentially next(after) it's current value. Thus, what come next/after 1? 2... etc.

Comment: i find that this method only works when my rank is by'1,2,3,4....' however, when its '1,1,3,3,5,5', this method is not working. but yours seems fine to me. do you know why?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but I would guess it has to do with the intersect and what you based the rank off of. Hard to tell without actual data unfortunately. Though, sometimes these things are better handled at the data source, depending on the source of course.